# Wickr me doesn't start on ubuntu 20

Tags: command-line

when trying to start wickr me via terminal I have the following error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
Gtk-Message: 17:05:21.891: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"

(WickrMe:13812): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:05:21.924: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1566:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(WickrMe:13812): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:05:21.932: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3616:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(WickrMe:13812): Gtk-WARNING **: 17:05:21.934: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4078:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
Gtk-Message: 17:05:22.042: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 17:05:22.043: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[0403/170522.176893:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale 
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /opt/qt512/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine ICU data not found at /opt/qt512. Trying application directory...
Installed Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /opt/qt512/translations/qtwebengine_locales. Trying application directory...
Qt WebEngine locales directory not found at location /snap/wickrme/507/usr/bin/qtwebengine_locales. Trying fallback directory... Translations MAY NOT not be correct.
Path override failed for key ui::DIR_LOCALES and path '/home/tuco/snap/wickrme/507/.QtWebEngineProcess'
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /opt/qt512/resources. Trying parent directory...
Qt WebEngine resources not found at /opt/qt512. Trying application directory...
[0403/170522.240100:WARNING:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(116)] locale_file_path.empty() for locale
```

can you help me how to solve?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software but it looks like an Android application.  You should provide more information including how you installed the software and the command(s) you are attempting.

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  There is no such release. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/device releases (also suitable for cloud use) that can use *snap* packages only.  By Ubuntu 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 20?  as it's a different product to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (desktop or server).

Comment: sorry i'm speaking about 20.04 LTS

Comment: I installed wickr me in snap store and it worked for a while. Now when i click on it nothing happens. If I try to start via terminal command I have the error above

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to AVX2 instructions.
Support recommends downgrading to candidate branch if AVX are not supported.

```
snap refresh wickrme --channel latest/candidate
```

https://support.wickr.com/hc/en-us/articles/1260806179370-Linux-Won-t-Open